# How to concat import modules like it was done with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I want to import modules in a single line with ES6 modules, like it was done with the require syntax shown in the example.

```
var configApi = require('somemodule').config.get('services').api;
```

I've tried

```
import configApi from 'somemodule'.config.get('services').api;
```

and

```
import configApi from 'somemodule';
const api = confiApi.config.get('services').api;
```

but none of them have work.

Comment: The first thing you tried is clearly invalid syntax - the second looks like it should work ... depending on what `thethingsio-domain` exports and how it exports it - when you say "none of them have work" ... what happens? what even is `thethingsio-domain` ... it's not an NPM package

Comment: Check what is being exported by ```thethingsio-domain```. If it doesn't export ```configApi``` then you cannot import that. For more info see ```https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import```

Comment: If the second doesn't work, try `import { config } from 'thethingsio-domain'; const { api } = config.get(…);` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
import * as configApi from "thethingsio-domain";
const api = confiApi.config.get('services').api;
```

but make sure you look at what is being exported by `thethingsio-domain`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using JavaScript dynamic importants.

```
import("/modules/my-module.js")
  .then((module) => {
    // do something 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  });
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import